# Oracle Protocol Adapter Error

Tags: oracle, connection, adapter, ora-12560

HI,
I've just installed Oracle 10 g Express Edition on to my laptop. The platform is Windows XP SP3. Installation went normally. BUt when I try to get connected to the Oracle database via SqlPlus I get "TNS Protocol adapter error".My laptop is on the network.I'd installed the same database on to a Windows Server 2003 and it works fine. What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you create the database as part of the installation?

Comment: When I install Oracle 10 g Express edition it does not ask me to choose anything else than the location of Oracle to be installed and the SYS password. I was not asked to create a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume this is `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`.  The [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12500.htm#sthref3449) describes it as a generic TNS error, but there are two very common causes of it.

1. The Windows service for OracleXE has not started, so the database is not up.
2. The Oracle SID is not set.

If the service is started then try setting the SID.  In a command window type:

```
C:>  set oracle_sid=XE
```

(or whatever you called it).  Then you should be able to connect to the database using SQL*Plus.  If this does solve your problem you should probably add it to the environment variables (System info, Advanced tab).

Comment: Thank you APC for your attention and contribution. After reading your answer I realized that I don't even have this Service in my services list. Only Oracle related services are OracleXEClrAgen,OracleXETNSListener and OracleMTSRecoveryService.Why wouldn't the setup file install that service?