# OracleXE installation and permission problems

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-xe-18.4

Reference:

[How to connect using PDB userid on Oracle 18c XE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256722/how-to-connect-using-pdb-userid-on-oracle-18c-xe)

[TNS Protocol adapter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782842/tns-protocol-adapter-error-while-starting-oracle-sqlplus)

Product I am trying to install / configure: OracleXE 18c

**Problem 1:**

Attempting to log in as described in the [Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/connecting-oracle-database-xe.html) returns the error shown below:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

**Problem 2:**

The following command fails immediately before asking for a password:

```
sqlplus system@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

```
 ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Enter user-name: system

Enter password:

ERROR:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

**Problem 3:**

I tried `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN;` as is mentioned in one of the the reference issues cited at the top of this post.
The command completes successfully. However trying run `STARTUP` as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/starting-and-stopping-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-831D014C-E163-45F6-9B44-611EE772E2E2)
results in an error:

```
SQL> startup;
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
SQL>
```

Running `whoami` at the windows command prompt returns my user name which has admin priviliges and is the same one used to install OracleXE.

Additional Background:

I am able to log in as follows:

```
sqlplus system@localhost:1521
```

When I installed Oracle XE it created tnsnames.ora and listner.ora using `mymachine.mydomain.com` as host.  The completion screen of the installer told
me to log in using localhost:1521 which does not work.  After several hours of research I discovered that if I change `mymachine.mydomin.com` to `localhost`
in tnsnames.ora and listener.ora I could log in as system@localhost:1521.  The above three problems remain however.

Running `select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'` as described in the ticket referenced above returns only one row: XE.  Should it also
return a row for XEPDB1?

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

listner.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\myname\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\myname\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME=XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\myname\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=XE)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME=XEPDB1)
      (ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\myname\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME=XEPDB1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 23-APR-2021 15:55:00

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                23-APR-2021 12:09:44
Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 45 min. 16 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\OracleClient\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\myname\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\mymachine\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEPDB1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XEPDB1", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

sqlnet.ora

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\OracleClient\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Comment: Please show also your sqlnet.ora

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov updated

Comment: Is the Windows service for the database running? If not you should start it.

Comment: @BobbyDurrett Yes I check it every few minutes. Listener service is running also.

Answer (score 0):

- Problem 1:

To use OS authentication on Windows your user should be in ORA_DBA group and sqlnet.ora must contain

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

*updated: I see NTS was configured already, so just check if you are in the ORA_DBA group*

- Problem 2:

[EZCONNECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntcli/specifying-a-connection-by-using-the-easy-connect-naming-method.html#GUID-1035ABB3-5ADE-4697-A5F8-28F9F79A7504): try this syntax with `//`

```
sqlplus system@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

- Problem 3:

You need to check the alert.log. You can save init parameters and post your parameter here:

```
alter system create pfile='c:/temp/init.ora' from spfile;
```

and then just post this file and startup errors from alert.log

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Confirmed I am in ORA_DBA group.

Comment: Regarding problem 2: syntax provided shows a long list of options but does not log in or prompt for password.

Comment: @sam have you set ORACLE_SID parameter before `sqlplus / as sysdba`?

Comment: Regarding ORACLE_SID - If you mean an environment variable - no, I have not set an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you omit password when connecting through sqlplus you need escaping.
This was my experience when I used WindowsOS. I just tried Easy Connect on my MacOS where it works with or without escaping.

```
REM password in clear text. 
C:\>sqlplus user/password@host:port/SERVICE_NAME
REM you will be prompted for password
C:\>sqlplus user@"\host:port/SERVICE_NAME\"
```

Best of luck!